# Collapsing raw data into single dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a data frame with a tonne of data I am trying to collapse. I can collapse based on measurement but there are other parameters I would like to persist. Here is an example of the data:

[image]

What I can do: use pandas dataframe pivot function to spread the measurement names across as columns.

```
df.pivot(columns="measurement", values="measurement_values", index="__ids__")
```

This is easy enough and it allows me to do a lot of the computations I need. What I would like is this:

[image]

edit-- here is the raw text. Note I have to change the actual values and the name as I cant release the actual data:

```
 dutOnLane  lane    chip    measurement value    __ids__
0   0   tt1 out1    1.88477E-06  4iNP04MFUEg7IdxYItmYBCr7rEUf02tG
0   0   tt1 err 123607   4iNP04MFUEg7IdxYItmYBCr7rEUf02tG
0   0   tt1 out2    1.16179E-06  4iNP04MFUEg7IdxYItmYBCr7rEUf02tG
0   0   tt1 noise   20.36525454  4iNP04MFUEg7IdxYItmYBCr7rEUf02tG
1   1   tt1 out1    1.25934E-06  x2jXp7LwidaMEvnzmRZsdajV8GVppxUV
1   1   tt1 err 78426    x2jXp7LwidaMEvnzmRZsdajV8GVppxUV
1   1   tt1 out2    7.37E-07     x2jXp7LwidaMEvnzmRZsdajV8GVppxUV
1   1   tt1 noise   20.5361943   x2jXp7LwidaMEvnzmRZsdajV8GVppxUV
2   2   tt1 out1    6.64165E-06  Qud21bKSCmeFHuheGGci95V2rLhuiywP
2   2   tt1 err 579353   Qud21bKSCmeFHuheGGci95V2rLhuiywP
2   2   tt1 out2    5.44544E-06  Qud21bKSCmeFHuheGGci95V2rLhuiywP
2   2   tt1 noise   19.73114325  Qud21bKSCmeFHuheGGci95V2rLhuiywP
```

So with the above I can achieve the spreading out of the measurement names. I can brute force and rip apart the dataframe, but from experience this is not as fast as using pandas functions to transform the dataframe and some tests have millions of measurements so it bottle necks a bit.

If anyone has a suggestion, or point to a resource I can reference that would be great!

---

Another edit. So I have made same progress but its a little wonky. I group by the ids (overall row) but the columns are a little messed up.

```
df_analysis.groupby(["__ids__"])[["vt_cond", "lane", "chip", "process"]].apply(lambda df: df.reset_index(drop=True)).unstack().reset_index()
```

The output looks as follows:

[image]

Ideally, the operation produces this output, but a single column of each. Its essentially creating n columns for n unique measurement names (has 133 measurement names, so its creating that many columns).

Comment: Can you please post your sample data and its expected output in a text format?

Comment: Also, what do the numbers in the output mean? Is 10 counting something?

Comment: @aaossa I updated the question. So I basically want to expand the measurement names as new columns and keep the remaining columns. __ids__ is essentially a row of data. All setup parameters are the same for a single __ids__, and I want to have each measurement as a column and finally keep each setup parameter (ie chip, lane) for each row

Answer (score 0):

I have a workable solution. I by no means know if this is the best solution (likely isn't)

```
def clean_unrolled_data(df_in):
    '''this function takes a raw unrolled dataframe and transforms it to a reable table'''
    group_columns = ["vt_opts", "lane", "chip", "process", "rate"]
    t = df_in.groupby(["__ids__"])[group_columns].apply(lambda df: df.reset_index(drop=True)).unstack().reset_index()
    raw_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=group_columns)

    for g in group_columns:
        raw_df[g] = t[g][0].values

    #now pivot the data
    measurements = df_analysis.pivot(columns='blockName', index='__ids__', values='blockValue').reset_index(drop=True)
    new_df = pd.concat([raw_df, measurements], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)

    return new_df
```

Basically what I do is I pivot the meausrements based off the row id ****ids****, and then group by the columns I want to keep. The data is organized in order according to the ids used so the pivot and the groupby *seems* to keep everything in order (need further testing). The function then outputs the same data witht the measurements spread across the columns still maintaining the other columns.